# How does an eclipse project search for external resources (like txt files) during runtime? My code is faultering

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having issues with this topic, see below:

I have 2 txt files in an eclipse subdirectory "resources" shown below:

[image]

I' trying to pass their name, and thus their contents, to a class which will return the number of lines contained in them.

see my **main** class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    int num_words = FileLineCount.countLines("Lexicon.txt");

    System.out.println("NUmber of lines: " + num_words);        
}
```

and my **FileLineCount** class:

```
public class FileLineCount {

    public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        try {
            byte[] c = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            int readChars = 0;
            boolean empty = true;
            while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
                empty = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                    if (c[i] == '\n') {
                        ++count;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }   
}
```

When I run this program, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Lexicon.txt
>   (No such file or directory)

Is this due to my txt files being in a subdirectory?  How does an eclipse java program search for external resources (like txt files) during runtime?

Comment: Is your project supposed to be a Maven project? If not how is the structure of your project? You just posted a portion of the project structure. It is difficult to say how your resources are related to the Java files reading these files.

Comment: @ujulu  It is not a Maven project.  It's a standard eclipse project.  I have all my source code under my "main" package in the "src" folder.  I also just arbitrarily keep my required text files under the "src" folder, as shown in the picture, as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to use a pure eclipse project. But I created an eclipse Java project with the following directory structure:

```
test_eclipse_proj/src
```

Then I created the following sub folders as follows:

```
test_eclipse_proj/src/main
test_eclipse_proj/src/resources
```

And I created a class, say `TestFileResource` in the `main` folder which contains your `main()` method. Inside of your `main()` method I made the following modification:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    int num_words = FileLineCount.countLines("../resources/Lexicon.txt");

    System.out.println("NUmber of lines: " + num_words);        
}
```

Finally, I made the following modification inside of the `countLines()` method:

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(TestFileResource.class.getResourceAsStream(filename));
```

With this small modification, the program runs and can read the input file.

In deed, I am not sure if the program is correct, because I added the following lines into the file `Lexicon.txt`:

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
```

Then the output from the program is:

```
NUmber of lines: 2
```

Hopefully, this should give you an Idea how to solve your problem.

And final advice from me: try to use some build tool instead of creating eclipse project :-)

Here you'll find the JavaDoc for the `getResourceAsStream()` method for more information:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ClassLoader.html

Comment: You are awesome.  Seriously, thank you so much!  it's working perfectly now.  And I'll read over getResourceAsStream() as you have linked.  But how did you know this would solve the issue?  What can it do that "FileInputStream" can't?

Comment: The problem with the `FileInputStream` is the path, or my understanding of it. The only occasions it worked for me are when I use either the absolute path or the current directory path; but neither of these are good solutions.

Comment: Continued ... So I started to use `getResourcesAsStream()` method. I only need to put the file resources in the class path and the class loader takes care of the rest. This comment is getting too long, so the best exlplanation can be found [here](http://javachannel.org/posts/how-to-access-static-resources/).

Comment: what folders/directories does the absolute path or the current directory path contain?  Is this an IDE or a JAVA thing?

Comment: The absolute path is, for example, `/home/yourName/file.txt` on a Unix systems or `C:/someDirectory/file.txt` on windows systems. And the current directory is the directory where you are running your program. The issue is Java issue and not of Eclipse.